# Using preferences in Firefox

Tags: firefox, xul

How do I access user preferences in Firefox? I have the following code:

```
var control = document.getElementById(control_id);
if (control) {
    control.setAttribute('color', nsPreferences.copyUnicharPref(prefstr, default_val));
}
```

But when I run this, I get the following:

```
Error: nsPreferences is not defined
Source file: chrome://backgroundtoggle/content/options.xul
Line: 9
```

I'm having trouble wading through the Mozilla documentation. How do I make this do what I want?

Comment: Actually, I was just referring to this answer, and I noticed this: "When you wish to put non-`<prefpane>` elements to prefwindow, you should place them after all of `<prefpane>`s. If you put other elements before the first `<prefpane>`, you possibly see strange behaviors about switching panes." This contradicts one thing that Mike Spross said. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/prefwindow#Issues_when_using_prefpanes_in_prefwindow -- try it out and see what happens I guess. Although you may not really need that script in your prefwindow, just in your main browser overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to include `nsUserSettings.js` in your `.xul` file:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/nsUserSettings.js" />
```

This is where `nsUserPreferences` is defined.

See [here](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fid419BA3E23A00B8481C9B4BE7F33B2E32B36ABF07.aspx) for an example `options.xul` file. The `script` tag should be the first child element of `prefwindow` to ensure it gets loaded before your own code does.

---

#### Additional Information

[This](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/index.html) looks like a decent tutorial on how to write Firefox extensions. It seems to do a good job of consolidating all the relevant information on mozilla.org in one place, and contains links to mozilla.org when you need more details on a topic being covered. I do wish the navigation was a little better, but what can you do? Use the navigation pane on the left-hand side and click *Tutorial* to get started. You have to move through each section using the navigation pane, which took me few seconds to figure out, as I was looking for 'Next' and 'Previous' links on the page.

Comment: Sometimes you are able to use nsPreferences, even without including the script. My guess is that this is because some other extension has loaded that script for you, leading you to believe that everything is okay. Then, a user who has far less add-ons than you do, tries to install your extension, and it doesn't work. Sneaky.